# Twig and Doctrine- Count each related entity and display in Twig loop

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a one to many relationship in doctrine.I want to count each related field and display them in Twig for loop

so far

A Vp is related to Voters.Vp has many Voters and Voters has one Vp
I want to count each related Voters per Vp

```
 public function getAllVp()
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->select('vp.id,COUNT(v.id) as num')
        ->from('Voters', 'v')
        ->join('v.Vp', 'vp')
        ->orderBy('v.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

I want this in Twig like

```
{% for vp in vps %}
 {{ vp.firstname }}
 {{ vp.num }}//number of voters
{% endfor %}
```

controller

```
   $vice_president = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Vp')->getAllVp();

    return $this->render('Bundle:Vp:all_vp.html.twig', array(
        'vps' => $vice_president,
    ));
```

doctrine

```
 fields:
    firstname:
        type: string
        length: 255
    lastname:
        type: string
        length: 255
    photo:
        type: string
        length: 255

oneToMany:
    voters:
        targetEntity: Voters
        mappedBy: vp
```

I got this error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 94 near 'vp, Voters v': Error: Class Project\Bundle\DuterteBundle\Entity\Vp has no association named Vp

How to correctly achieve this in Doctrine?

**Update**

voters.orm.yml

```
manyToOne:
    vp:
        targetEntity: Vp
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: voters
        joinColumn:
            name:  vp_id
            referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

I can achieved this by simply calling the related 'voters' and add a filter in Twig.But my intention is to count the data in doctrine, reuse it in other templates or convert it to json for the future,e.g in Angular JS

```
 {% if vp.voters|length > 0 %}
   <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
     <td>{{ vp.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ vp.getFullName() }}</td>
     <td>{{ vp.voters|length|number_format }}</td>  
   </tr>            
{% endif %}
```

Above is a working code but I want to do the count in Doctrine , not in template

Expected result

```
id  fullname     counts
1   George Bush  45
2   ali gail     1999
4   Mae Young    45
......
```

Comment: Please, can you post doctrine mapping for Voter entity ?

Comment: @ Delphine I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can remove `mappedBy: null` in your Voter mapping.

**PHP oriented :**

Ok you can try this PHP solution to add a new method in your entity Vp like :

```
public function getVotersCount(){
    return count($this->voters);
}
```

And in your twig view you can do :

```
{{ vp.getVotersCount() }}
```

**Doctrine oriented :** *(http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)*

In your Vp Entity orm mapping :

```
fields:
    firstname:
        type: string
        length: 255
    lastname:
        type: string
        length: 255
    photo:
        type: string
        length: 255

oneToMany:
    voters:
        targetEntity: Voters
        mappedBy: vp   
lifecycleCallbacks:
    postLoad: [ countVotersOnPostLoad ]
```

And also a new attribute, a getter and countVoters method :

```
protected $votersCount;

public function getVotersCount(){

    return $this->votersCount;
}

public function countVotersOnPostLoad ()
{
    $this->votersCount = count($this->voters);
}
```

And in your view, simply do :

```
{{ vp.votersCount }}
```

Comment: This definitely the possible answer.1. Do you know how to sort this based on (get.VotersCount()) and 2. In other templates, I want to display only the vp with the highest number of voters?

Comment: Maybe you can try something like that :

`public function getVpWithMaxVoters(){    return $this      ->createQueryBuilder('vp')
        ->from('Voters', 'v')
        ->leftJoin('v.Vp', 'vp')
        ->orderBy('COUNT(v.id', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->setMaxResult(1)
        ->getResult()
    ;
}` in your repository

But you should post a new topic

Answer (score 0):

My work around for this is to create a service.

```
<?php

namespace Project\Bundle\DutBundle\Twig;

class AllVpExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
 protected $em;

 public function __construct($em)
 {
   this->em = $em;
 }

 public function getFunctions()
{
   return array(
//this is the name of the function you will use in twig
  new \Twig_SimpleFunction('number_votes_vp', array($this, 'b'))
 );
}

public function getName()
{
  //return 'number_employees';
  return 'vp_app_extension';
}   

public function b($id)
{
 $qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
 $qb->select('count(v.id)')
  ->from('DutBundle:Voters','v')
  ->join('v.vp','c')
  ->where('c.id = :x')
  ->setParameter('x',$id);
$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult(); 
return $count;
}
```

}

Now in order to count each vp's related voters, I can call a service and send the result to twig

```
  public function all_vpAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $vice_president = $em->getRepository('DutBundle:Vp')->findAll();

    //communicate to service container
    $data = $this->container->get('duterte.twig.vp_app_extension');
    $datas = array();

    foreach ($vice_president as $value) {
       $datas[] = array('id' => $value->getId(),'firstname' => $value->getFirstname()  . ' ' . $value->getLastname(),'numbers' => (int)$data->b($value->getId()));
    }

    $vice = $datas;

    return $this->render('DutBundle:Vp:all_vp.html.twig', array(
        'vps' => $vice,
    ));   

   //or we can wrap this in json

    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');

    $jsonContent= $serializer->serialize($vice,'json');

    return $jsonContent;
}
```

With this set up, I can wrap this into json and and using custom twig filter, I can display data sorted either in Angular or in plain Twig template or both

By the way, my view

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        #img-responsive{
        height: 320px;
        /*width: 300px;*/
    }
 </style>
 {% endblock %}
 <div class="section-heading">
    <h2>Best Tandem Of the Day</h2>
 </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/img/dut.jpg" id="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>President</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/img/unknown.jpg" id="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Vice-President</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  Search Here: <input type="text" placeholder="search" ng-model="searchMe"/><br />
<table class="table">
    //names//
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Middlename</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td>//x.id//</td> 
            <td>//x.firstname//</td>
            <td>//x.numbers//</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
</div>  
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed" id="table1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Bet</th>
                <th>Votes</th>
                <!--th>Photo</th-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for v in vps | sortbyfield('numbers') %}
                {% if v.numbers > 0 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ v.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ v.firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ v.numbers }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
    });

    app.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("{{ path('vp_president') }}")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.names= JSON.parse(response);
        });
   </script>    
 {% endblock %}
```